# Getting the current value of a counter used in setInterval javaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, setinterval

Suppose I define the following function

```
export const startMoving = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // Do something…
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
    return intervalId;
};
```

Although 'counter' is defined with let in the function, it works, but my question is: How do I get the value of 'counter' after a while?

Rafael

Comment: declare counter outside of `startMoving` and export it as well

Comment: @Bravo That'll limit the use of the function / counter to only a single `startMoving` call

Comment: @CertainPerformance - true, but the code as shown isn't likely to be called more than once. As it accepts no arguments it would perform the same thing every time it is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return not only the interval ID, but also a function that returns the current value of `counter`.

```js
const startMoving = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // Do something…
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
    return [intervalId, () => counter];
};


const [intervalId, getCounter] = startMoving();
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => document.body.textContent = getCounter());
```

```html
click here
```

Comment: I need to save the value in a variable, so I did: 
const [anIntervalId, getCounter] = startInterval(addLocation)
anInterval is ok, but getCounter isn't
when I console.log(getCounter()), it says0.

Comment: You'll need to wait at least one second before calling `getCounter`, else it'll return 0